# Gradient of $X \mapsto \mbox{trace} \left( X^T A X \right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

<sub>I think the question is close to [Derivative of trace of inverse of a matrix function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417236/derivative-of-trace-of-inverse-of-a-matrix-function)</sub>

---

I have a function:

$$f(X) = \mbox{trace} \left( X^T A X \right)$$

and I am trying to derive $df/dX$

Update: I know that, for function $g(X) = X^TAX$

$\frac{dg}{dX} = (A+A^T)X$

Then now I need to calculate $f(g(X))$.

I tried to apply chain-rule:

$\frac{df}{dX} = \frac{df}{dg} * \frac{dg}{dX}$

And we already know $\frac{dg}{dX}$. But what is $\frac{df}{dg}$?

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: I am trying to use chain rule - but somewhat stuck in beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frobenius product (:) is a convenient notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the function, then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= {\rm tr}(A^TXA) = A:XA = X:AA^T \cr
df &= X:(A\,dA^T+dA\,A^T) = (X^TA+XA):dA \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= (X^T+X)A \cr
}$$
where the cyclic property of the trace were used to rearrange terms in the Frobenius products.

Comment: Hi, it seems your answer is different from https://www.psi.toronto.edu/matrix/calculus.html? They give the answer as $X^T(A+A^T)$. Might you elaborate?

Comment: @mommomonthewind In Matrix Calculus there are 2 common [layout coventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). I prefer the convention where the gradient of a scalar function wrt a matrix has the same shape as the matrix; your reference uses the other convention.  If you advance on to tensor calculus, there really is no choice. The concept of *transpose* becomes ambiguous, therefore a quantity like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ijk}}$ must be indexed (or shaped) the same as $X_{ijk}$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Could you explain why $A:XA=X:AA^T$? I did not really get it.

Comment: @mommomonthewind The cyclic/transpose properties of the trace means you can write things like $$\eqalign{ {\rm tr}(ABC)&={\rm tr}(CAB)\cr &={\rm tr}(C^TB^TA^T)}$$ So in product form, you can write things like $$\eqalign{X:YZ&=YZ:X\cr &=Y^TX:Z\cr &=XZ^T:Y}$$

Comment: So many thanks @greg. Just a final thing: from the second line how can you come up to the third line. For instance, if $df = (X^TA + XA)*dA$ (normal production operation), we can have $df/dA$. But here is the Frobenius product, so in fact $df= trace((X^TA+XA)^T.dA)$ and how can we derive $df/dA$?

Comment: Consider a gradient wrt a 3rd-order tensor $$\eqalign{G_{ijk}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ijk}},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,df&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k} G_{ijk}\,dX_{ijk} }$$ Note that a triple-contraction product is needed to evaluate the differential via the gradient.

For a matrix (aka a 2nd-order tensor) a double-contraction product is necessary.

Only for a vector (aka a 1st-order tensor) can you use a single contraction, i.e. a normal matrix product.